# jquery post is it ajaxrequest?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

i been trying to get this to work for solid 3 hours. im doing a jquery post but some where in the line im doing something wrong but i dont get what.

in my method i check if its a ajaxrequest and if it is i return a string message based on the outcome.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostJquery(ContactViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Email))
            {
                return Content("success");
            }
            else
            {
                return Content("Fail");
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("About");
        }
    }
```

my jquery and html looks like this.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   {%>
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email) %>
<br />
<br />
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title) %><br />
<input type="submit" value="Save" id="button" />
<%} %>


<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.2.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {            
        $('#button').click(function (e) {
                            $.post('/Home/PostJquery', { viewModel: $('form').serialize() }, function (data) { alert(data); });                
        });
    });

</script>
```

what it does is go into the method and redirect to the site about because its not a ajaxrequest, if i remove it it returns success but it takes me to a blank page with the text success writen. it dont trigger success in alert. what im i possibly doing wrong? should i use .post or .ajax?

thanks for input folks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cancel the default action of the button which is to submit the form by returning false:

```
$(function () {            
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.post('/Home/PostJquery', $('form').serialize(), function (data) { 
            alert(data); 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also notice the way parameters are passed. The `.serialize()` method already prepares the request so that's what you should send as second argument.

but a better way to AJAXify a form is to subscribe for the `.submit()` event of this form:

```
$(function () {            
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (data) { 
            alert(data); 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And even better way is to use the [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which turns your code into:

```
$(function () {            
    $('form').ajaxForm(function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Remark: make sure you set the proper content type on your server when returning from an AJAX request.

Comment: Thanks man i tried the function(e), e.preventDefault(); with no luck. i totaly missed the return false in the documentation. you saved my day Darin.

Comment: how you mean set proper content type? can you give me a quick example?

Comment: @Dejan.S, like this: `return Content("success", "text/plain");` or if you are using Json: `return Json(new { success = true });`